# PHP Header: Param value got truncated after #

Tags: php, httprequest

I'm using following code for redirection in PHP

```
header("Location:restaurantsList.php?msg=Restaurant 100#we updated successfully");
```

In `restaurantsList.php` when i'm trying to get `request parameters` then getting following array.

```
Array ( [msg] => Restaurant 100 )
```

Param value is getting truncated after `'#'`.

If a pass any normal text in param (without #) then i'm getting whole string as it is.

Is there any solution to get string as it is, even if string will be containing `#`?

Comment: Try encoding the params and sending it and decoding it when you receive them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [URL encode](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) special characters in your query string so your URL would look like:

```
header("Location:restaurantsList.php?msg=Restaurant%20100%23we%20updated%20successfully");
```

Answer (score 1):

The `#` symbol is used for anchor links and therefore must be encoded if used as "data" in the URL. You can use the [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) PHP function for this. The `#` symbol would translate to `%23`

Answer (score 1):

in url `#` behave as hash tag that called `Fragment identifier`

Javascript:  `window.location.hash`;  // this is return sting that start with `#` tag

You will need to encode url component in server side code to keep message

```
header("Location:restaurantsList.php?msg=". 
      urlencode("Restaurant 100#we updated successfully"));
```

OR

```
header("Location:restaurantsList.php?msg=Restaurant 100%23we updated successfully");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `urlencode` the string after `msg=`:

```
header("Location:restaurantsList.php?msg=" . urlencode("Restaurant 100#we updated successfully");
```